# Never stop growing of MariaDB service memory on Windows

Tags: innodb, mariadb, windows

I have this strange problem in a Win7-4GB machine with MariaDB v. 10.1.18 using only InnoDB tables.

mysqld.exe service memory grows until the OS error out of memory, it take some hours but at the end it happens.
I check what it is doing and I have this problem also with 0 active connection, so I'm sure, it doesn't depend of query complexity or client activity.
I also try to restart the service without any clients/applications and it slowly restarts growing.

My mariaDb configuration file **my.ini** is very short:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/mariadb/data
innodb_file_per_table=0
```

These are some variable about inno memory (got from default configuration):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size     134217728
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216
thread_stack    297984
```

And this is the InnoDB status output:

```
=====================================
2018-02-10 17:16:20 0x14e4 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 43 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 0 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 577 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 577
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 24
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 11
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 50, OS waits 18
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 220, OS waits 0
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 50.00 RW-shared, 220.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 45315
Purge done for trx's n:o < 45025 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 906
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 281475146910504, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 281475146909576, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: native aio handle (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: native aio handle (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: native aio handle (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: native aio handle (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: native aio handle (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: native aio handle (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
1089 OS file reads, 52 OS file writes, 7 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 71707708
Log flushed up to   71707708
Pages flushed up to 71707708
Last checkpoint at  71707699
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
10 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 137953280
Dictionary memory allocated 63836
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       7133
Database pages     1057
Old database pages 410
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1023, created 34, written 35
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 1057, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=3292, Main thread ID=4936, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Looking at "Total large memory allocated" seems everything ok. However windows task manager shows mysqld service growing over 3GB.
The only particular configuration I set is "innodb_file_per_table=0".

**EDIT**

I solved dumping all, removing "innodb_file_per_table=0", reinstalling all the MariaDB service and reimporting the dump. I'm not sure if removing "innodb_file_per_table=0" was the key or it was just rebuilding all databases.

Comment: Is the OS a 32-bit version?  Or 64?  What about MariaDB?  What version of MariaDB?

Comment: It is 64bit. MariaDb version 10.1.18